# Hidden files create by Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

When i create Core Data NSManagedObjectSubclass somehow Core Data created files, that i actually cant find. You see, in my project i have

```
#import "Menu+CoreDataClass.h"
#import "Menu+CoreDataProperties.h"
```

And if i use cmd+click on them, i actually opening this files. However, there is no such files in my app, i cant event find them with spotlight on mac.

Problem is, when i try to create actual files, compiler through me an error - duplicate symbols for architecure, etc..

So, my question is quite simple, how to find and get rid of this files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode will generate these files for you and store them in the derived data directory of your project. It automatically (most of the time) regenerates them if you change the model.

To change this behaviour, in the model editor change the **Codegen** option in the data model inspector to **Manual / None**, and generate the files yourself manually. You may need to clear derived data to prevent the duplicate symbol error.

Answer (score 1):

These files are created automatically by Xcode.
[Xcode:Entity codegen property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kcymq.png)

You need to select Manual/None codegen property for your entity. After this make product clean.